# Argument of click method in jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am trying to bind a click function to an HTML element.
So i tried this :-

```
$("#buttonId").click(alert("hey")); // does not work.
```

And then i tried this :-

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() {
    alert("hey");
}); // works perfectly fine.
```

Since alert is also a function, why i can't directly pass it.
Can somebody please put some light on this ?

Click method documentation is available here http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second example you're passing a function to the `click()` method ***but not calling it***. When someone clicks on the element, jQuery will *then* call the function for you.

In the first example however, you're calling "`alert("hey")`" (which returns `undefined`), and *that* value is passed to the `click` method.

Comment: in essence, when you follow a function by parentheses - (), you are actually firing the function right away, and not giving it to the handler to fire when clicked.

Comment: also the function you pass there is an handler which I think can't accept parameters but the event parameter. Is that right?

Comment: @Onheiron: In the majority of cases yes, but if you used `trigger()`, you can pass additional arguments. (http://api.jquery.com/trigger/);

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, I understand your point now..Well explained

Answer (score 1):

The `click` method take an argument of handler type while `alert("hey");` is a function call that is neither a handler no it returns a handler, that'y this call is invalid .